# How to change grid scale group in Diagrams.net from 4 to 5?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

There is a grid settings in the Diagram properties in Drow.io/Diagramms.net. I can set the cell size and lines color.
However, when I scale out, the cells group in 4x4 groups, so the group cell is c*4 size.

[image: cells group in 4]

Is it possible to set this multiplier to 5? Like, I set 1mm for grid, and the group will look like 5mm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click Extras > Configuration in the editor and change gridSteps to 5:

{
"gridSteps": 5
}

Click Apply and then reload a page.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why the heck this isn't the default?